# Office 365 document viewer - doesn't work with URL have port number

Tags: office365-apps, microsoft-document-viewer

I am using office-365 document viewer to read the DOC/DOCX files in the browser.
The public IP of the server have port number eg: `xyz.com:3453`
The IP is accessible publicly and I have already cross check the [Document won't open](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-office-documents-online-1cc2ea26-0f7b-41f7-8e0e-6461a104544e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.)

Please help.